# About UITapGestrueRecognizer in Swift

Tags: swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have made a view subclass of UIView.Then, I added UITapGestureRecognizer to it but when I tap on the view, it don't respond to it.

Code:

```
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTapHandler:")

    self.maskView!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
```

selector:

```
    func singleTapHandler(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    print("xxx")

    dismiss()
    }
```

Comment: Check the 3D view (Debug view Hierarchy) and see if the view is in front or any other view is on top of it...!

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have enabled user interactivity:

```
self.maskView!.userInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the maskView on top of the view,  and the frame not equals to CGRectZero

Answer (score -1):

Check if you added `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your view, and use that  `tapGesture.delegate = self`

Your tapGesture should be like `let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "singleTapHandler")`, there is no need of `:`

Then your function can

```
func singleTapHandler(){
    //action
}
```

Lastly, make sure you tap on the view you added the tap gesture.